# Function "effects" fails to find data in a model object loaded from a rds file

Tags: r

I am encountering a problem when trying to call the effects function (from the package effects) on a `lm` object loaded from a `rds` file. I need to save the files, since I adjust several models in a loop and then later retrieve the models in order to produce graphs for some of the models.

Heres is an example of the problem:

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df1<-data.frame(var1,var2)
lm1<-lm(var1~var2,data=df1)
saveRDS(lm1,"lm1.RDS")
rm(lm1,var1,var2,df1)
loaded<-readRDS("lm1.RDS")
library(effects)
eff<-allEffects(loaded)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the `effects::allEffects` function does not do this but it's fairly simple to recover data from a model:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(var1 =loaded$model$var1, var2=loaded$model$var2)
> eff<-allEffects(loaded)
> eff
 model: var1 ~ var2

 var2 effect
var2
         -2          -1           0           1           2 
-0.08501500 -0.09133397 -0.09765294 -0.10397191 -0.11029088
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer! It did work, however I wonder if someone could explain why the effects::allEffects function behaves this way...

Comment: A good question for: `maintainer("effects")` returning "John Fox <jfox@mcmaster.ca>". He's very responsive to questions. A consummate teacher. I would not hesitate to write him.